# Django 1.6: Login redirection button not working on Firefox and Safari

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, safari

I have this in my template to allow people to post reviews. If the user is not logged in it takes him to the login page when clicked on the write review button, and then redirect backs to the same page upon successful login. It works fine on Chrome but when used on Firefox and Safari nothing happens when the button is clicked.

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated and reviewed == True  %}
  <h4><a class="writebtn"href="">Already Reviewed!</a></h4>

  {% else %}
  <button class="btn btn-primary"><a class="writebtn"href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Write Review</a></button>

  {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'meddy1/login.html'}, name="login"),
```

I'm also using bootstrap for the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"><a class="writebtn"href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Write Review</a></button>
```

with

```
<a class="btn btn-primary writebtn" href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Write Review</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! It works! Can you explain me why it's working with a tag rather than the button tag ?

Comment: Bootstrap makes anchors with a "btn" class look identical to buttons. I think Firefox and Safari have some problems with nested <button>- and <a>-Tags.